# NSolve returns input

Tags: equation-solving

[image]

I'm using `NSolve` to find the interaction of two curves, which the `ContourPlot` shows there is a cross point around (0.04,0.45) which is approximately agreed by `FindRoot`. But `NSolve` cannot solve the equations and output what I inputted. May I asking how can I let `NSolve` working even with low precision, thank you.

```
NSolve[{-((
    6.25*10^24 (3.14023*10^17 PolyLog[3, -E^(-2951.37 u)] - 
       3.14023*10^17 Sqrt[b]
         PolyLog[3, -E^(2951.37 u)]))/(-3.14023*10^17 PolyLog[
        3, -E^(-2951.37 u)] - (
      3.14023*10^17 PolyLog[3, -E^(2951.37 u)])/Sqrt[
      b])^2) == -59.2544, 
  3.14023*10^17 PolyLog[3, -E^(-2951.37 u)] - (
    3.14023*10^17 PolyLog[3, -E^(2951.37 u)])/b^(3/2) == 
   3.28153*10^22/b^(3/2), 0 < u <= 0.05, 0 < b < 1}, {u, b}, Reals, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 100]
```

Comment: It may not be possible to use `NSolve`. `FindRoot` returns `{u -> 0.028987, b -> 0.459139}`.

Comment: That polylogarithm suggests that you should have used `FindRoot[]` in the first place.

Comment: but I have hundreds of `(T1, RH1)` pairs, for each pair I need solve to the cross points. by using `FindRoot`, I found that for the different initial value it gives different result, thus, it is hard to input a suitable initial value for each pair.

Comment: I can't run this here, but I'm rather surprised `NSolve` didn't throw a message re: specifying `WorkingPrecision->100` when you give machine precision input.  (or did you cut that off the screen grab?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the `FindRoot` calculation more robust, `Rationalize` the decimal numbers, use higher precision, and provide guesses that approximately bracket the intersections.  For instance,

```
FindRoot[Rationalize[{-((6.25*10^24 (3.14023*10^17 PolyLog[3, -E^(-2951.37 u)] - 
    3.14023*10^17 Sqrt[b] PolyLog[3, -E^(2951.37 u)]))/(-3.14023*10^17 
    PolyLog[3, -E^(-2951.37 u)] - (3.14023*10^17 PolyLog[3, -E^(2951.37 u)])
    /Sqrt[b])^2) == -59.2544, 
    3.14023*10^17 PolyLog[3, -E^(-2951.37 u)] - (3.14023*10^17 
    PolyLog[3, -E^(2951.37 u)])/b^(3/2) == 3.28153*10^22/b^(3/2)}, 0], 
    {{u, .01, .04}, {b, .25, .75}}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]

(* {u -> 0.0289870031031739971379139981316, b -> 0.459139486674871987547206867589} *)
```

Of these changes, `Rationalize` seems to be most important.  I hope this helps.